# The integral $\int (1+|x|)^{-N} \text{d}x $ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The function $\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^N}$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and by $|x|$ I mean the norm, is clearly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$ hence measurable. Now apparently, for any dimension $n$, we can find $N$ large enough so that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^N} \text{d}x <\infty.
$$

How can the above result be proved?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it in polar coordinates: it is easy to see that the surface area of an $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$ is some constant times $r^{n-1}$ (of course this constant is the area of the unit sphere, $S_{n-1}$), and the integrand only depends on $r$, so the integral becomes
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{dx}{(1+\lvert x \rvert)^N} = S_{n-1} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^N} \, dr, $$
which you can bound in the usual way for one-dimensional things (look at the behaviour as $r \to 0$ and $r \to \infty$ of the integrand, and elsewhere it's continuous).